# Editing a patched file

Tags: version-control, patch

I have a general workflow question: I get a patch from a co-worker and would like to further edit one of the affected files. How do I isolate my changes? I'd like to be able to keep my changes when re-patching in the latest changes from my co-worker. 
Feel free to point out special features of your favorite version control system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git as your version control system and create different branches for you and your co-worker. After that you can work on your own **branches** with out interfering with each other. And you can always isolate your changes/patch in a **commit**.

When you want to "re-patch" the latest version from your co-worker, you can either use **git merge** to merge your co-worker's updates into your branch or use **git rebase** to redirect the branching point of your branch to a newer version. Git can automatically merge different versions unless there is an conflict.